# Можно ли в синхронихированный лист(коллекцию) засунуть атомарный инт или в целом атомарные значения?

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация, android-threads, атомарность

Можно ли? И самое главное, есть ли в этом смысл? Если можно и/или есть смысл можете простые примеры показать буду очень благодарен!
Вот допустим, где `<Integer>`, можно ли поставить в том числе `<AtomicInteger>`?

```java
Collection<Integer> syncCollection = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: `И самое главное, есть ли в этом смысл` - вот в этом вся соль. Коллекция защитит от параллельных изменений списка, содержащегося в ней. Но не внутренностей конкретных объектов, содержащихся в этом списке

Comment: `Integer` и `AtomicInteger` имеют фундаментальное отличие - первый `immutable`, а второй - нет. От этого и стоит отталкиваться изначально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Можно ли?

можно

> И самое главное, есть ли в этом смысл?

гипотетически можно притянуть за уши

> ... простые примеры ...

например, если в параллельных потоках Вы работаете со списком неких счётчиков.

> можно ли поставить в том числе АтомикИнтеджер?

нельзя, но можно использовать Number, тогда в этот список можно будет складывать Integer, AtomicInteger, BigInteger, Long, AtomicLong, итд